# Erlang/OTP R15B01: ct_line replacement?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

Erlang/OTP R14B04 offered [ct_line](http://erldocs.com/R14B04/common_test/ct_line.html), a parse transformer to insert line numbers (`otp_src_R14B04/lib/common_test/src/ct_line.erl`). I can't find that in R15B01, so I guess it must have been removed. Do you know of a replacement with similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ct_line` transformer was removed in R15 (see the [commit](https://github.com/erlang/otp/commit/f43c0a51cd15b2b0f8adba4bb9ec5531dd9d8820)) since [line numbers in exceptions](http://erlang.org/download/otp_src_R15B.readme) were added to the runtime system (finally!).